# SSIS: Export to Dynamic Excel File

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2008

I am trying to create a project that will produce a separate excel file for every account in a specific table. The first steps to pull the data into a temp file and load an array variable with the accounts for the loop, this is working fine.

I am getting the 2 errors below. And when I execute the package it fails on the export to excel data flow task.

> Error 1   Error loading RAW_DATA_EXPORT.dtsx: The connection string
>   format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the
>   form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection
>   string with zero components is set on database connection manager.
>
> Error 2   Error loading RAW_DATA_EXPORT.dtsx: The result of the
>   expression ""\\server\DATA\Status\Testing\Filename" + 
>   @[User::Accts] + ".xls"" on property "ConnectionString" cannot be
>   written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be
>   set on the property.

This is what my dynamic connection string looks like evaluated:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\server\DATA\Status\Testing\Filename03500.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES";
```

I think the issue is since the excel file are non-existent, the validation fails when it gets to the step. From what I found online I need to either create the sheets through a a script task (not fond of) or use a variable value to create the sheet in the file. I have not been successful on either.

Comment: Try to change the property `Delay validation` to `TRUE` for the Excel connection and the dataflow task

Answer (score 0):

> (...) since the excel file are non-existent, the validation fails when it gets to the step.

Have you tried delaying validation in the Data Flow task that exports to Excel? Check Data Flow's properties window.

Comment: The solution was to delay validation of the data flow, but also have a SQL execute task that would create the "table" in the excel file aka create the sheet.